# Input with ClickHandler not rendered in GWT

Tags: gwt, java-8

I'm using GWT 2.6.0 and I'm following the [StockWatcher tutorial](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/buildui.html).

Simplified, this is my code:

```
private Button sendButton = new Button("send");
private VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();

public void onModuleLoad(){
    // this works
    mainPanel.add(sendButton);
    RootPanel.get("stockList").add(mainPanel);

    // until I add a Click Handler:
    sendButton.addClickHandler(event -> addStock());
}

private void addStock(){
    //TODO: implement
}
```

The button is not rendered. However, if I remove the click handler, the button becomes visible.

I'm completely new to GWT and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm using `ant devmode` to run in development mode and I'm using Firefox 26.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that [lamdas](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html) a java8 feature are not supported yet by GWT:

```
   sendButton.addClickHandler(event -> addStock());
```

Here's how to add a click handler

```
  Button b = new Button("Click Me");
  b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      // handle the click event
    }
  });
```

Comment: Odd, the one-liner lambda is the result of refactoring the `new ClickHandler()...` in IntelliJ IDEA. It seems I don't quite understand Java 8 and the lambdas as the code with the anonymous inner class does work. Thanks

Comment: your code looks fine as is, i think @Dmitry has a point, and gwt may not deal with java 8 class files.

Comment: @aepurniet yes, I realized that, i updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

I not sure, that gwt 2.6 supports java8 and lambdas. 
To be convinced of this, try to compile you project to javascript.

> Java 7 is supported and is now the default. (This can be overridden
>   using 
>   -sourceLevel 6)
>   http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_0

Comment: Java 7 is supported, as noted in the link you posted, but Java 8 is *not* supported yet. Java 8 isn't even official yet, we've only got pre-releases. Without Java 8, you can't yet have lambdas.